# Can a plagiarized answer marked for moderator attention be helpful and at the same time remain undeleted?

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism, moderator-intervention

Can a plagiarized answer marked for moderator attention be helpful and at the same time remain undeleted?

This discussion have a reference to the question [How to run a Chromium Browser with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567901/how-to-run-a-chromium-browser-with-selenium) where I published an answer. OP on being successful in solving his problem through my answer published his own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54568928/1) mentioning:

> @DebajanB , thank you very much. I edited your code and now I am can run Chromium

The only change was:

- The absolute path of the *Chrome Canary* binary which I have mentioned explicitly and OP needs to set using `setBinary()` method which wasn't super clear from the image OP provided.

So, I added a comment and raised a *flag* for *moderator attention*.

Now seems there is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54568928/revisions) to the verbatim of OP's answer and the *moderator attention flag* was marked helpful. But the *plagiarized answer* continues to survive.

My questions are:

- Was I correct to raise the *moderator attention flag* for *plagiarism* in this case?
- Are *plagiarized answer* here to stay with tangential edits?
- If the *flag* was helpful why did the *plagiarized answer* survive?

Comment: He attributed the code to you, so this is not plagiarism. It would only be plagiarism if he claimed he came up with the code himself. The mod reviewing your flag has edited the answer and made the attribution somewhat more proper, thus taking action on your flag. Why do you think this answer should be deleted?

Comment: Given that you did not feel the need to write an answer that fits to the code in question, I see no problem there. The correct path was in the initial question, but your answer (for whatever reason) decided to use a completely different path.

Comment: Mods will many times mark flags as _helpful_ even if not honoring the flag directly. They do that so the flag rejection doesn't count against you, and so you understand that your input was acknowledged. It means _"this was helpful"_, not _"you were absolutely right and we'll get right on it"_.

Comment: @BDL There is no viable way to justify if OP's path `C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chrome-win\\chrome-win\\chrome.exe` is the exact path of _Chrome Canary binary_ as the default path on _Windows OS_ is the path I have used in my code which is **`C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe`**

Comment: @yivi _we'll get right on it_ When? How? Impact?

Comment: You misinterpreted my comment. It **does not** mean _"you were absolutely right and we'll get right on it". _

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth So now on-wards whenever I ask a question I need to construct my own answer attributing each answerer without the need to _accept_ / _upvote_ any of them. Did I get your comment right?

Comment: You absolutely **not need** to upvote or accept other posts. That's entirely optional.

Comment: @yivi Though _accepting_ and _upvoting_ is _optional_ in nature but those are essential contributions which helped this eco system to _mature_ and _evolve_ over the decade. Individuals do can posses different perspectives.

Comment: @DebanjanB That makes no sense at all. You don't need to do anything after writing a question. Nor does anyone need to upvote and accept anything.

Comment: Also note, you talk about him not upvoting, but he only has 1 rep. He doesn't have the privilege to upvote.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Perhaps my question wasn't about _upvoting_ or _answering_. Let's stick to the main objective of  plagiarism.

Comment: You wre the one who brought up votes in the first place. Your question is simple: how can it be a flag _helpful_ and the flagged answer remain undeleted. That I addressed in my first comment. The there is the other side of actually arguing if this answre was or was not plagiarism... but you'd have to agree that that's a different question. Maybe you should edit your question so it's clearer what's what you really want answered.

Comment: @yivi Alright, now can you help us answering to the three canonical questions please?

Comment: I've helped you with what I believe is the main point. A moderator addressed the other point. I wouldn't post an answer because I believe the question is too broad in its current form.

Comment: @yivi Your comment doesn't helps me either. How am I going to improve my question with that feedback?

Comment: At this point, I don't think it's a plagiarism (it's attributed properly), but I'd argue if the answer adds any new insights compared to the existing answer? Do we want duplicated answers with trivial differences?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were not wrong to flag an answer that you thought was plagiarised for moderator attention.

However, *this particular* answer wasn't plagiarised; the answer clearly states where they got the code from. Even in [the original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54568928/1), it was attributed to you. Another moderator edited in a link to your answer for full compliance with [our attribution requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

I'll admit that they should have made it clear exactly what they'd changed in the code, but that's not an issue here.

If you provide an answer that *almost* works, then the OP is perfectly correct to post a "corrected" version of the code in an answer of their own. It's no different to if someone else provides an answer that basically the same as yours but with modifications to get it working *for them*.

Ideally, they should upvote your answer as helpful, but as others have said, all voting on Stack Overflow is optional.

Comment: _"corrected" version_ by the means of changing the _absolute path_ of a binary which users can keep anywhere within his/her system?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes. They posted what worked *for them*. It may not work in all circumstances, but that's for you to point out in your answer.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that, if the OP can post an answer that modifies the path to work for them, couldn't anyone? Everything I read says the OP isn't special, so I don't think they should have special privilege here, even if it is their question.

Comment: @TheWanderer there's nothing stopping anyone posting a modified answer that solves the problem *for them*.

Comment: @ChrisF but if the only change is a word in the path, is it really a significant change or widely applicable answer? There will probably be a few people with the same username, but the generic path answer already covers all cases, imo.

Comment: @TheWanderer In this case you're right, but I was thinking of the more general case where the change isn't just that of the username.

Comment: @ChrisF definitely. I was focusing mainly on this case. Honestly, the problem could probably be avoided altogether by using a relative path (`%localappdata%` takes you right to the current user's AppData\Local\ directory).

Comment: Although I don't know enough about Windows programming to know if path placeholders work.

Comment: @ChrisF Honestly, I didn't wanted to pull in the technical aspect about the change which worked for OP. Even I am not sure if OP have multiple versions of _Chrome Canary_ installed within his/her system. The _windows path_ I suggested in my answer is the **default** path chosen  by the _Chrome Canary installer_ which I felt could not only answer OP's question but will also be _helpful_ / _useful_ to the community users in the long term.

Comment: @TheWanderer You're more than welcome to feel that a given person's derivitive version of an answer isn't useful. If you feel that way you're more than welcome to reflect that opinion with your votes.  But the issue under discussion here is whether it is *plagiarism*, which it most certainly is not, even if it's not a *useful* derivative work.